# Mininet Script Error: type object 'OVSSwitch' has no attribute 'OVSVersion'

Tags: python, mininet, openvswitch

I am receiving the following error:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 1162, in start
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 1163, in <genexpr>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 1129, in intfOpts
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 1072, in isOldOVS
AttributeError: type object 'OVSSwitch' has no attribute 'OVSVersion'
```

while I ran the following Mininet script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, Host, Node
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch
from mininet.node import IVSSwitch
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
from subprocess import call

def myNetwork():

    net = Mininet( topo=None,
                   build=False,
                   ipBase='10.0.0.0/8')

    info( '*** Adding controller\n' )
    c0=net.addController(name='c0',
                      controller=Controller,
                      protocol='tcp',
                      port=6633)

    info( '*** Add switches\n')
    r1 = net.addHost('r1', cls=Node, ip='0.0.0.0')
    r1.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')
    s3 = net.addSwitch('s3', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    r2 = net.addHost('r2', cls=Node, ip='0.0.0.0')
    r2.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')
    s5 = net.addSwitch('s5', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)

    info( '*** Add hosts\n')
    h3 = net.addHost('h3', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.3', defaultRoute=None)
    h4 = net.addHost('h4', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.4', defaultRoute=None)
    h1 = net.addHost('h1', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.1', defaultRoute=None)
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.2', defaultRoute=None)

    info( '*** Add links\n')
    net.addLink(h1, s3)
    net.addLink(h2, s3)
    net.addLink(r1, s3)
    net.addLink(s3, r2)
    net.addLink(h3, s5)
    net.addLink(h4, s5)
    net.addLink(s5, r1)
    net.addLink(s5, r2)

    info( '*** Starting network\n')
    net.build()
    info( '*** Starting controllers\n')
    for controller in net.controllers:
        controller.start()

    info( '*** Starting switches\n')
    net.get('s3').start([c0])
    net.get('s5').start([c0])

    info( '*** Post configure switches and hosts\n')

    CLI(net)
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    myNetwork()
```

generated by miniedit.py. The code at line number 1070 at [node.py](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/mininet/node.py) seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works I don't know why:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, Host, Node
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch
from mininet.node import IVSSwitch
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
from subprocess import call

def myNetwork():

    net = Mininet( topo=None,
                   build=False,
                   ipBase='10.0.0.0/8')

    info( '*** Adding controller\n' )
    c0=net.addController(name='c0',
                      controller=RemoteController,
                      ip='127.0.0.1',
                      protocol='tcp',
                      port=6633)

    info( '*** Add switches\n')
    s1 = net.addSwitch('s1', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    s2 = net.addSwitch('s2', cls=OVSKernelSwitch)
    r3 = net.addHost('r3', cls=Node, ip='0.0.0.0')
    r3.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')
    r4 = net.addHost('r4', cls=Node, ip='0.0.0.0')
    r4.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')

    info( '*** Add hosts\n')
    h1 = net.addHost('h1', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.1', defaultRoute=None)
    h2 = net.addHost('h2', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.2', defaultRoute=None)
    h3 = net.addHost('h3', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.3', defaultRoute=None)
    h4 = net.addHost('h4', cls=Host, ip='10.0.0.4', defaultRoute=None)

    info( '*** Add links\n')
    net.addLink(h1, s1)
    net.addLink(h2, s1)
    net.addLink(h3, s2)
    net.addLink(h4, s2)
    net.addLink(s1, r3)
    net.addLink(s1, r4)
    net.addLink(s2, r3)
    net.addLink(s2, r4)

    info( '*** Starting network\n')
    net.build()
    info( '*** Starting controllers\n')
    for controller in net.controllers:
        controller.start()

    info( '*** Starting switches\n')
    net.get('s1').start([c0])
    net.get('s2').start([c0])

    info( '*** Post configure switches and hosts\n')

    CLI(net)
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    myNetwork()
```

Answer (score 2):

Was facing the same issue, it seems that the library has some initialization happening at `net.addSwitch()`, i.e. you need to **first call** `net.addSwitch()` **at least once**, before any of the `addHost()` / `addLink()` ones.

Answer (score 0):

In your original version, you had

```
net.addLink(r1, s3)
```

where you needed to have

```
net.addLink(s3, r1)
```

You appear to have fixed it inadvertently while refactoring variable names.